# CSS Fixed / Absolute positioning to an earlier relative?

Tags: css, positioning, fixed

I have a sort of super special-case here I guess.

I'm working with many includes. Right now I'm coding in an included content-file. There I need a lightbox which has a 20% black background covering the whole page, including the header which is fixed itself and set in prior PHP files to z-index 200.

The `#overlay-wrapper` is, because of these includes, placed in `#content`, which is for other reasons `position: relative`. The wrapper has 100% width and height and z-index of 1000. Still, logically, it only covers the content-area and not the whole viewport.

Basically I now need a way to tell the `#overlay-wrapper` to be positioned relatively to the body without telling the content not to be relative, because as mentioned I need it to be relative in other cases.

Putting the overlay in another file would be a pain and I'm just curious if it's possible to tell a box to be positioned relatively to an "earlier" parent and not just the first he finds.

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code. :) As for the question, if you have access to jQuery UI you could use `.position()`.

Comment: an absolutely positioned element will always be relative to the first relatively positioned parent it has.  When you say the overlay is 100% width and height, should that be of the screen or the #content div?  If it is the screen then just make it fixed instead of absolute as fixed is always positioned relative to the viewport

Answer (score 0):

As long as `#overlay-wrapper` is within `#content` and `#content` is relatively positioned, `#overlay-wrapper` will always be positioned relative to `#content`. There is no way to work around this without relocating `#overlay-wrapper` in the DOM.

You will need to move `#overlay-wrapper` out of `#content`, either by modifying your PHP includes (by perhaps even moving it to a separate include of its own and including that elsewhere), or by using JavaScript to relocate it on page load.